# Why ng-container showing my td tag and template element does not showing my td tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template, ng-container

I want to show  `td` tag if my statement is true. So I am using  `<template>` element to check that condition. **But after rendering the screen I couldn't see the `td` tag inside the `template` element**.

[image]

```html
<table class="ui-grid-row ui-row" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed" cellspacing="0">
  <tr style="width:100%">
    <td style="width:5%" class="ui-border" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }">{{datavalue.FieldPrefix}}</td>
    <td style="width:30%" class="ui-border" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }">{{datavalue.FieldName}}</td>

    **//here am using template element**
    <template *ngIf="datavalue.IsOverridable">
                                        <td style="width:59%" class="ui-border" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even, highlight:datavalue.IsMandatoryElementDataMissing}"
                                            (click)="AddNewDialog(datavalue)">
                                            <span *ngIf="!datavalue.IsMultiRowExist" [innerHTML]="datavalue.FieldValueCobmination==null?'':datavalue.FieldValueCobmination"></span>
                                            <span class="grid leftalign" *ngIf="datavalue.IsMultiRowExist"><img class="image" title="Multi Line" src="assets/images/MultiLine.png" /></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </template>


  </tr>
</table>
```

**But it's working fine** if am using `<ng-container>` element instead of `<template>` element.

[image]

```html
<table class="ui-grid-row ui-row" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed" cellspacing="0">
  <tr style="width:100%">
    <td style="width:5%" class="ui-border" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }">{{datavalue.FieldPrefix}}</td>
    <td style="width:30%" class="ui-border" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }">{{datavalue.FieldName}}</td>


    **//here am using ng-container element**
    <ng-container *ngIf="datavalue.IsOverridable">
      <td style="width:59%" class="ui-border" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even, highlight:datavalue.IsMandatoryElementDataMissing}" (click)="AddNewDialog(datavalue)">
        <span *ngIf="!datavalue.IsMultiRowExist" [innerHTML]="datavalue.FieldValueCobmination==null?'':datavalue.FieldValueCobmination"></span>
        <span class="grid leftalign" *ngIf="datavalue.IsMultiRowExist"><img class="image" title="Multi Line" src="assets/images/MultiLine.png" /></span>
      </td>
    </ng-container>


  </tr>
</table>
```

### Questions : -

> - Why `ng-container` does show my `td` tag and `template` element does not shows my `td` tag?
> - Explain when I would use `ng-template` instead of `ng-container`?

Comment: One thing i know is `template` is an invalid element into `tr` tag.

Comment: @SankarRaj then what about ng-template into tr tag?

Comment: It will be taken care by angular... is template an angular directive? correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: template if not angular directive. its html tag that prevents rendering it in browser, but you can render it via javascript :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use with  `ng-template` like this

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="condition"><div>...</div></ng-template>
```

The difference with `ng-container` that you can use directives like this `*ngFor` that require template but it will not create anything in html.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">{{item }}</ng-container>
```

but when you use `ng-template` you will need to write to full form

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" 
   [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</ng-template>
```

See also

- https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3216-template-vs-ng-container-for-grouping-dom-nodes-in-angular-2-4-4.htm

Comment: But what is the relations with my problem?

Comment: And explain when I would use ng-template instead of ng-container?

Comment: But I don't know, why I can't see my td tag inside the template element?

Comment: Updated the answer